# Deleting rows from an access table based on multiple conditions in python along with a date field

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to delete rows from an access database table, based on two columns one which is released_by and released_date.

```
Sudo code

WHERE released_by  = '27' and released_date would change based on the day of the month.
```

Released_Date if day ==1 then delete previous month's data else current months data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pyodbc
import calendar
import xlrd
import defusedxml
from defusedxml.common import EntitiesForbidden
from xlrd import open_workbook
defusedxml.defuse_stdlib()

# connecting to access database
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Desktop\Insights.accdb;')
insights_dbcurs = conn.cursor()

select_auto_releases = "SELECT * FROM RELEASES WHERE RELEASED_BY = '27'"
autoreleases = insights_dbcurs.execute(select_auto_releases).fetchall()
#display(autoreleases)

for row in autoreleases:
    previousmonth = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
    previousmonth = previousmonth.strftime("%m - %Y")
    currentmonth = datetime.now()
    currentmonth = currentmonth.strftime("%m - %Y")
    if ((row.autoreleases['RELEASED_DATE']).strftime) ==1:
        try:
            delete = 'DELETE * FROM RELEASES WHERE RELEASED_DATE = ? and RELEASED_BY = ?'
            insights_dbcurs.execute(delete,{'RELEASED_DATE':currentmonth},{'RELEASED_BY':'27'})
        except:
            delete = 'DELETE * FROM RELEASES WHERE RELEASED_DATE = ? and RELEASED_BY = ?'
            insights_dbcurs.execute(delete,{'RELEASED_DATE':previousmonth},{'RELEASED_BY':'27'})

insights_dbcurs.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It does not work. I get:

> AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'autoreleases'

if I remove `Row.autorelease`, I get

> sql has 0 attributes, 2 being passed.

How do i avoid this. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Try `if ((row.RELEASED_DATE).strftime) ==1:`

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks i tried. i noticed while running the code now is that RELEASED_DATE is being pulled in as a string. `'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime' or strftime '`. when i tried to convert it to a date format. also i tried .`((row.RELEASED_DATE).astype(date).strftime ==1`it did not work as well.  The above one worked apart from this new fallout.

Comment: If `row.RELEASED_DATE` is a string then either use `.strptime(...)` to parse it and then `.strftime("%m - %Y")` to re-format it, or just use string manipulation to re-arrange the substring parts to match `.strftime("%m - %Y")`

Comment: since i am using the current date to check which month's data to be deleted i changed it to this `if datetime.now().strftime('%d') !=1:`
       ` try:`
            `delete = 'DELETE * FROM RELEASES WHERE RELEASED_DATE = ? and RELEASED_BY = ?'`
            `insights_dbcurs.execute(delete,{'RELEASED_DATE':currentmonth},{'RELEASED_BY':'27'})`
       ` however i get this  `SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'> returned a result with an error set`. Error points near the execute statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider re-factoring your code for several issues:

1. `try/except` is usually used for handling runtime exceptions and errors, not application logic. Use the `if/else` for these situations.
2. Remove the unneeded `for` loop as you are not deleting row by row since no unique identifier is being passed into `DELETE` statements. In actuality, you are running the deletion process across whole table if the logic passes that current row not filtered to that one row.
3. Use pure SQL with one `DELETE` statement and avoid the Python handling of time elements which as you see maintains conversion issues from the database. MS Access SQL does have date functions such as `Date()` (current date) and `DatePart()` for month/day extractions. Additionally, MS Access *can* run complex subquery logic in `DELETE`.

**SQL**

Using `IN` subquery for both date conditions. NOTE: `ID` should be replaced with unique identifier of table. Check `SELECT` version of query prior to `DELETE` version.

```sql
DELETE FROM RELEASES r
WHERE r.ID IN
  (SELECT sub.ID  
   FROM RELEASES sub
   WHERE sub.RELEASED_BY = ? 
     AND (
           (
            DatePart('m', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m', Date()) - 1
            AND DatePart('yyyy', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('yyyy', Date())
            AND DatePart('d', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = 1
           )
          OR 
           (
            DatePart('m', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m', Date())
            AND DatePart('yyyy', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('yyyy', Date())
            AND DatePart('d', sub.RELEASED_DATE) > 1
           )
        )
  )
```

**Python**

Passing parameters with dates handled in Access engine.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'...')
insights_dbcurs = conn.cursor()

sql = """DELETE FROM RELEASES r
         WHERE r.ID IN
           (SELECT sub.ID 
            FROM RELEASES sub
            WHERE sub.RELEASED_BY = ? 
              AND (
                    (
                     DatePart('m', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m', Date()) - 1
                     AND DatePart('yyyy', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('yyyy', Date())
                     AND DatePart('d', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = 1
                    )
                   OR 
                    (
                     DatePart('m', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m', Date())
                     AND DatePart('yyyy', sub.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('yyyy', Date())
                     AND DatePart('d', sub.RELEASED_DATE) > 1
                    )
                  )
           )"""

insights_dbcurs.execute(sql, ('27',))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the modification. I have tried the same and continue to get an error at the execute section.  `ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression 'SUB.RELEASED_BY = Pa_RaM000\n                            AND \n                                (\n                                    (DatePart('m',SUB.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m'.Date())-1\n                                        AND DatePart('d',SUB.RELEASED'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")`.

Comment: Seems like a missing parenthesis issue but I cannot see it. I just copied this query into MS Access and it saved without issue. Access does NOT save queries with syntax errors. Did you make any changes from this post anywhere in Python? I am seeing *Pa_RaM000*. Is that a parameter?

Comment: This suggestion might be especially helpful in this case because Access tends to be extra accommodating when it comes to type juggling. For example, Access will automatically convert a date-like string passed in place of a true date (e.g., `DatePart("m", "2018-09-12")` works), while Python is much stricter about such things (e.g., `d.month` works if `d` is a `date` but not if `d` is a `str`).

Comment: @Parfait - `Pa_RaM000` is the internal representation of a query PaRaMeter when Jet/ACE is preparing a statement. It can also be found in Jet/ACE SHOWPLAN output.

Comment: i checked once again there is not missing parenthesis. this Pa_RaM000 is coming when i use '27' at the end. I have not added anything additional. If i use '?' then i get the error `SQL has 0 parameters 2 parameters being passed.`

Comment: `sql  = """DELETE FROM RELEASES r
            WHERE r.ID IN
                (
                    SELECT SUB.ID 
                        FROM RELEASES SUB
                            WHERE SUB.RELEASED_BY = ?
                                AND 
                                    (
                                        (
                                            DatePart('m',SUB.RELEASED_DATE) = DatePart('m'.Date())-1`

Comment: `AND DatePart('d',SUB.RELEASED_DATE)=1
                                         )
                                OR
                                        (
                                        DatePart('m',SUB.RELEASED_DATE)=DatePart('m',Date())
                                            AND DatePart('d',SUB.RELEASED_DATE)> 1
                                         )
                                    )
                )"""
insights_dbcurs.execute(sql,('27',))`

Comment: This is how i used it. I replaced id with my data as well to see.. RELEASE_NO still i go the same error.

Comment: Are you maintaining line breaks exactly as I posted? Note: this triple quote string is valid Python. Your posts here show equal and commas flushed together without spaces which I rarely do. If you removed spaces, make sure there are spaces before and after `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and other clauses. Also, a one-item tuple for parameter *does* require a comma after item: `('27',)`

Comment: @Parfait exactly the way you have posted it.

Comment: @Parfait it worked. There was an extra single space showing up which was causing the error. Thanks for the code. I checked the database the data not only for the current month also for the same month previous year was deleted

Comment: Made a change to code to add the year. so it worked. Thanks for the help. :)